# Llamar función de CodeIgniter con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo un problema al llamar la función mensaje con ajax:

HTML

```html
<form id="formulario" role="form" 
      action="<?php echo  base_url();?>index.php/welcome/guardar"
      class="form-horizontal cform-1" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="email" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Email" name="correo" id="correo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Numero de Celular" name="celular" id="celular">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Asunto" name="asunto" id="asunto">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <textarea name="mensaje" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"
                placeholder="Mensaje" id="mensaje"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: $("form").attr("action"),
    type: $("form").attr("method"),
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(respuesta) {


      alert(respuesta);
      $("#nombre").val("");
      $("#correo").val("");
      $("#celular").val("");
      $("#asunto").val("");
      $("#mensaje").val("");

      $.ajax({
        alert("entra ajax correo");
        url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/welcome/correo"); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
          alert();
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Error!');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Controlador CodeIgniter

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("mensaje_model");
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home-layout-1.php');
    }

    function guardar(){
        //El metodo is_ajax_request() de la libreria input permite verificar
        //si se esta accediendo mediante el metodo AJAX 
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $nombre = $this->input->post("nombre");
            $correo = $this->input->post("correo");
            $celular = $this->input->post("celular");
            $asunto = $this->input->post("asunto");
            $mensaje = $this->input->post("mensaje");

            $datos = array(
                "nombre" => $nombre,
                "correo" => $correo,
                "celular" => $celular,
                "asunto" => $asunto,
                "mensaje" => $mensaje

                );
            if($this->mensaje_model->guardar($datos)==true)
                echo "Registro Guardado";
            else
                echo "No se pudo guardar los datos";
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }

    function correo(){
        echo "entra a correo";
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('javier_fr@outlook.com', 'Francisco Javier Ferruzca Rojas');
        $this->email->to('luis.salazaruteq@gmail.com');
        //$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
        //$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
```

Comment: hola, podrias poner tu html form, para conocer el codigo completo, asi como porque realizas el segundo llamado por ajax, te podrias ahorrar ese paso llamando ese metodo posterior al metodo guardar

Comment: Hola claro que si

Comment: Que problema tienes?

Comment: quiero llamar a mi funcion de CodeIgniter llamada mensaje

Comment: sera esto --> echo "Registro Guardado";??? xq no tienes un funcion con ese nombre mensaje?

Comment: perdon a la de correo

Comment: url: '<?php echo base_url("welcome/correo"); ?>',

Comment: Una pregunta tu ajax esta en la mismo hmtl o es un js aparte?

Comment: $.ajax({
     alert("entra ajax correo");

Este codigo esta mal

Answer (score 2):

No puedes añadir un `alert()` dentro de la llamada a Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    // Esto no puedes hacerlo, este es un array con los parámetros de la petición AJAX 
    alert("entra ajax correo"); 
    url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/welcome/correo"); ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        alert(); // Aquí si puedes, porque estás dentro de una función
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Error!');
    }
});
```

Elimina el `alert()` y comprueba si te funciona la petición.